# vuejs Incorrect component definition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have two components - 'HelloIndex' and 'HelloShow'.

The problem is that when I try to do this

```
this.$router.push({name: 'HelloShow', params: {id: 1}})
```

, then the 'HelloIndex' component is loaded instead of 'HelloShow'.
 In my router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloIndex from '@/components/HelloIndex'
import HelloShow from '@/components/HelloShow'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/index',
      name: 'HelloIndex',
      component: HelloIndex,
      children: [
        {
          path: ':id/show',
          name: 'HelloShow',
          component: HelloShow
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

HelloIndex.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'helloIndex',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'INDEX'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

HelloShow.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'helloShow',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'SHOW'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="show">show</button>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  methods: {
    show () {
      this.$router.push({name: 'HelloShow', params: {id: 1}})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

What's wrong with the names of the components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent component which has children should contain `<router-view></router-view>` in `<template>` tag. Your `HelloIndex.vue` file can look like:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'helloIndex',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'INDEX'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If you want to have both components at the same level, so `HelloShow` won't be a child of `HelloIndex` you might want to edit your routes.

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/index',
      name: 'HelloIndex',
      component: HelloIndex
    },
    {
      path: ':id/show',
      name: 'HelloShow',
      component: HelloShow 
    }
  ]
})
```

More informations about this topic can be found in `vue-router` [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html)